# Create line numbers on pre with CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I try to style a code pre box with line numbers in front of each line. I prefer to do it with CSS only. This is what I have done

```css
pre {
  background: #303030;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-top: 4px solid #00aeef;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
}
pre span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
pre span:before {
  counter-increment: line;
  content: counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #888
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <span>lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>lorem ipsum,\ </span>
  <span>lorem ipsum.</span>
  <span>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>lorem ipsum</span>
</pre>
```

However, all the lines have the number 1. The increment doesn't work. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2xkgt7s/)

1. What I am doing wrong?
2. What is the browser compatibility with this CSS only solution?

Comment: Why not use an OL tag?

Comment: @Graham If I tell you that I totally forgot it, will you believe me? :P :P

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Why does the the counter not increment?**

You are not resetting or creating the counter at the parent tag level. If you add the following line to the `pre` selector, the code will work fine. When you don't create the counter (using a `counter-reset`) at the parent level, each element would create its own counter and then increment it.

```
counter-reset: line;
```

---

**When does a counter get created?**

From the [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#counter-properties):

> The counter-reset property creates new counters on an element.
>
> The counter-set and counter-increment properties manipulate the value of existing counters. They ***only create new counters if there is no counter of the given name on the element yet***.

In this case what happens is that we haven't created a counter by using the `counter-reset` property and so the `counter-increment` property in the `span:before` pseudo-element selector would create a counter of the given name and increment it.

---

**How does the counter get to know the current value?**

Again from the [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#creating-counters):

> If an element has a previous sibling, it ***must inherit all of the sibling’s counters***. Otherwise, if the element has a parent, it ***must inherit all of the parent’s counters***. Otherwise, the element must have an empty set of counters.
>
> The element then ***inherits counter values from the immediately preceding element in document order***.

Here since the counter is only created in the pseudo-element, its parent (the `span`) is not aware of its creation and so the siblings of this `span` doesn't inherit the counter. Since it doesn't even inherit any counter, it doesn't get the current value from the preceding element either.

---

**Why does creating the counter on parent work?**

When the counter is created at the `pre` tag level, the counter is then passed on to each of its children elements (that is, each `span` and in turn each `span:before` would know about or inherit this counter) and now the increment statements in the `span:before` would only increment the value of the counter which it received from the parent.

Now since each `span` inherits the `line` counter from its previous sibling, they will also inherit current value from the preceding element in the document order and thus it keeps going up from 1 to 2, 3 etc.

---

**Why does using counter-increment on span or pre work?**

As you've guessed, the counter-increment property ***creates*** a new counter when there is no existing counter and so adding `counter-increment: line` on the `span` will create a counter on the first span that is encountered. Now, since each sibling of the `span` inherits this counter, it doesn't create a new one every time and rather just inherits the value from the preceding element. Thus this approach will work but it is always better to create the counter explicitly using a `counter-reset` statement.

---

**How is the browser support?**

Browser support for CSS counters is unbelievably good. It is not a new thing in CSS and [support for it is available even in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters).

---

**Demo:**

```css
pre {
  background: #303030;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-top: 4px solid #00aeef;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  counter-reset: line;
}
pre span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
pre span:before {
  counter-increment: line;
  content: counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #888
}
```

```html
<pre><span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum,\ </span>
<span>lorem ipsum.</span>
<span>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: Nice; I always - mistakenly - thought that we had to define the `counter-increment` on the non-pseudo element; I hadn't realised at all that using `counter-reset` on the parent element (wrapping the 'counted-elements') would work as well. The ongoing mysteries of CSS! :)

Comment: @DavidThomas: I've finally completed fleshing it out fully. Pinging you just in case you are interested :)

Comment: How to optimize a little bit to make all the bars vertical align better when line numbers have different width?

Comment: @MaxPeng: Giving the pseudo-element a `width` that is wide enough to accommodate all possible numbering values would make them align better (like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/enbuoLb0/)). But the thing is you must assign an arbitrary width depending on the max value you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You have to increment `line` in your span:

```
pre span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    counter-increment: line;
}
```

Have a look at this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2xkgt7s/1/).

Comment: It works, but when my `<span>` count is more than 10,000, it takes dozens of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to reset the counter on a previous / higher loaded item, check out https://jsfiddle.net/n2xkgt7s/2/ `pre { counter-reset: line; }`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `<pre>` you may consider ordered list `<ol>`, which already comes with right aligned numbering (nicer for when number of digits jumps, e.g. 9 -> 10).
`<li>` also does not need the closing tag `</li>` (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags), which saves typing.

```css
ol {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre; 
}

li::marker {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ol><li>lorem ipsum      
<li>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum
<li>lorem ipsum,\ 
<li>lorem ipsum.
<li>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum
<li>lorem ipsum
<li>lorem ipsum
<li>lorem      
<li>ipsum
<li>&gt;&gt; lorem ipsum
<li>lorem ipsum
</ol>
```

However, `::marker` styling seems limited (`list-style-type`). E.g. removing the period or `vertical-align: super` seems to needs other workaround (back to `li:before` and `counter`).

Comment: Thanks - This also solves a problem where I want my users to be able to select the lines of text without selecting the numbers.

Comment: This is an incomplete solution. Marking up code as an ordered list is inaccessible as it will be presented as a numbered list of items to screenreaders and not a block of code with line numbers.