# Looking for a way to produce directly pretty code section in HTML with VIM

Tags: html, css, vim, copy-paste

I would like to generate, with VIM, pretty HTML code of code snippet (C, python or others).

Right now, I know only the command under VIM "`:TOhtml`" but the result seems to be too basic.

Here's an example of what I would like to get (with lines number and round corners) :

[image: example]

Does anyone know a way to produce quickly this kind of presentation ?. Even if VIM can't do it, is there a tool which allows to take the raw code section and generate directly HTML code with necessary customisable CSS ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

I found partially a solution by firstly showing the lines numbers with ":%set nu" and doing ":TOhtml".

So I get for example the following code snippet :

```
<pre id='vimCodeElement'>
<span id="L1" class="LineNr">  1 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&quot;clFFT.h&quot;</span>
<span id="L2" class="LineNr">  2 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;stdio.h&gt;</span>
<span id="L3" class="LineNr">  3 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;stdlib.h&gt;</span>
<span id="L4" class="LineNr">  4 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;string.h&gt;</span>
<span id="L5" class="LineNr">  5 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;math.h&gt;</span>
```

Then, I set in CSS style :

```
.LineNr { color: #007399;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

My issue happens when I am on Firefox or Chrome :

1) In the first case (FF), if I copy from html page the code, then when I paste into nedit for example, each line is separated of 1 blank line from the other ones.

2) In the second case (Chrome), the code selection is pasted correctly but the lines numbers also appears, I thought that "`user-select: none;`" could prevent this behavior.

Anyone could help me to debug it ?

Thanks

**UPDATE 2 :**

I tried the solution suggested by `zeppelin` but the HTML code generated by "`:TOhtml`" command into `vim` is of form :

```
<span class="Comment">/*</span><span class="Comment"> Allocation of 2D arrays </span><span class="Comment">*/</span>
  x =  malloc((size_tot_y)*<span class="Statement">sizeof</span>(<span class="Type">double</span>*));
  x0 =  malloc((size_tot_y)*<span class="Statement">sizeof</span>(<span class="Type">double</span>*));

  <span class="Statement">for</span>(i=<span class="Constant">0</span>;i&lt;=size_tot_y-<span class="Constant">1</span>;i++)
  {
    x[i] = malloc((size_tot_x)*<span class="Statement">sizeof</span>(<span class="Type">double</span>));
    x0[i] = malloc((size_tot_x)*<span class="Statement">sizeof</span>(<span class="Type">double</span>));
  }
```

or another part of form :

```
printf(<span class="Constant">&quot;Time step</span><span class="Special">\n</span><span class="Constant">&quot;</span>);
  scanf(<span class="Constant">&quot;</span><span class="Special">%lf</span><span class="Constant">&quot;</span>,&amp;dt1);
  printf(<span class="Constant">&quot;Convergence </span><span class="Special">\n</span><span class="Constant">&quot;</span>);
  scanf(<span class="Constant">&quot;</span><span class="Special">%lf</span><span class="Constant">&quot;</span>,&amp;epsilon);
```

Both above HTML code have not necessary a `<span>` tag in front of each line of input code.

Don't you think that my first method is not good (there is a blank line when copy/paste in an editor like nedit) because of the presence of different  tag on each line, I mean after the first one which is always `<span id="L1" class="LineNr">  "n-th line" </span>` ?

For example, let's take this line :

```
<span id="L1" class="LineNr">  1 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&quot;clFFT.h&quot;</span>
```

Does problem come from the others `<span>` tags (`<span class="PreProc">#include </span>` and `<span class="Constant">&quot;clFFT.h&quot;</span>`) ??

It seems these 2 another tags produce carriage return when I copy a part of code, that would explain the blank line when I paste it in a text editor, doens't it ?

Regards

**UPDATE 3 :** I didn't find anything new about my attempt to remove blank lines when I copy/paste a code initially generated by `VIM` command `:TOhtml`, with line number for each starting of code line. For example, I show you again the generated HTML code :

```
<pre id='vimCodeElement'>
<span id="L1" class="LineNr">  1 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&quot;clFFT.h&quot;</span>
<span id="L2" class="LineNr">  2 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;stdio.h&gt;</span>
<span id="L3" class="LineNr">  3 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;stdlib.h&gt;</span>
<span id="L4" class="LineNr">  4 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;string.h&gt;</span>
<span id="L5" class="LineNr">  5 </span><span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="Constant">&lt;math.h&gt;</span>
```

I don't want lines numbers to be selected when I copy/paste some code from the page. That's why I used `user-select: none;` into my CSS for `<span` tag.

Maybe, the solution is to remove the carriage return (which seems to be double once I paste the code in a text editor because there are blank lines between each copied lines of the code).

But I don't know how to remove the second carriage return when I select some code and copy it into Copy/Paste text buffer.

I found an interesting discussion on the following link but I didn't understand all the subtilities  : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1273836

If someone had some idea or clues, this would be nice to tell it to me.

Thanks

Comment: solution is partialy done for rounded corners with CSS. and what about the generation of non-selectable line numbers ?

Comment: I could insert line number with ":set nu" before the command ":TOhtml" but these line numbers are selectable with mouse when I want to copy/paste the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php), and pipe your buffer through it:

```
%!highlight --style andes -I --style-infile=/tmp/custom.css -S c -l -F gnu
```

- --style andes ("andes" theme)
- --style-infile=/tmp/custom.css (add CSS styles from /tmp/custom.css)
- I - is for *include style* (inline CSS)
- S - is for *syntax* (language = `c`)
- l - is for *line numbers*
- F - is for *formatting* (`gnu` conventions)

*/tmp/custom.css* (adds round corners)

```
pre {
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

**Sample output**

[image]

Comment: I have just tested your solution but the line numbers are still selectable when I want to copy/paste the code, I am going to see if there's an option to prevent this selection.

Comment: I found out solution using "-moz-user-select: none;", thanks

Comment: still an issue about the behavior of copy code snippet and paste it into a text editor (like nedit), see my **UPDATE 1** above

Comment: I've been able to reproduce your cut-and-paste issue, and it is definitely caused by the `user-select:none;`, not sure on how to fix it, but maybe you can switch off the generated line numbers and try some "content:before" CSS solution instead, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842277/create-line-numbers-on-pre-with-css-only) (the line numbers added this way are selectable, but are not copied into a cut-and-paste buffer).

Comment: :zeppelin could you take a look on my **UPDATE 2** message to try debugging my issue with copy/paste in text editor ? Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least in recent versions of Vim (8.1, in 2018) there is `g:html_prevent_copy` and you can do `let g:html_prevent_copy = "n"` to make line numbers uncopyable when generating HTML with `:TOhtml`.