# Add Line Number to existing HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add line numbers to existing html with unequal line height - many types of font size and also images.
each line look like -

```
<div id="1"><right><span>line 1</span></right></div>
<div id="2"><right><span>line 2</span></right></div>
<div id="3"><right><span>line 3</span></right></div>
```

is there simple way to add line numbers that will be vertically align?
thanks

Comment: define explicitly elements width or use html TABLE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspiring from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842277/create-line-numbers-on-pre-with-css-only) question, I have developed a solution for your question. You can use the [`counter-reset and counter-increment property`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp) to achieve this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
              counter-reset: line;
            }
            .container .lineNum {
                display: block;
                line-height: 1.5rem;
            }

            .container .lineNum:before {
                counter-increment: line;
                content: counter(line);
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: .5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="1" class="lineNum"><right><span>line 1</span></right></div>
        <div id="2" class="lineNum"><right><span>line 2</span></right></div>
        <div id="3" class="lineNum"><right><span>line 3</span></right></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, i never knew something like `counter-increment: line;` existed in css. Well you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little automated paragraph counter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxNum = 0;//how many lines should be prepared (Takin in considersation, there would be more wrappers) 
  $(".NumeredTextBlock").each(function() {//create counter for each .NumeredTextBlock wrapper
    var line = 1;//start with number 1
    $("p", this).each(function() {//look for paragraph elements inside wrapper
      $(this).addClass("line" + line);//add class with line number
      line++;
      if (maxNum < line) maxNum = line;//set the maximum number of lines used in HTML DOM for wrapper
    });
  });
  var prepStyle = "";//prepare css style with line numbering
  while (maxNum--) {//prepare as many styles as the max number in document
    prepStyle += ".line" + maxNum + ":before{content:'" + maxNum + "'}";
  }
  $("#numbers").html(prepStyle);//add prepared styles to the HTML DOM
  console.log("resulting generated <style id='numbers'>"+prepStyle+"</style>")
});
```

```css
.NumeredTextBlock p {
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.NumeredTextBlock p:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="NumeredTextBlock">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dol</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<style id="numbers"></style>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have requirement listing automatically use `<OL>`    tag 
other way is no add deffrent tag like this

```css
div span {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
    <ol>
    <li> list </li>
    <li> list </li>
    <li> list </li>
    <li> list </li>
    </ol>
    
    
    
 <div id="1"><right>line <span>1</span></right></div>
<div id="2"><right>line <span>2</span></right></div>
<div id="3"><right>line <span>3</span></right></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div>span:first-of-type {
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

td,
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some str length<br/>Some str length</td>
    <td>105</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>shorter</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>

<div>
  <span>Some str length<br/>Some str length</span>
  <span>105</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>shorter</span>
  <span>102</span>
</div>
```