# How to make code editor-like line numbers using solely CSS?

Tags: css, text-editor, line-numbers

This code below for the most works. But when I type inside the lines, and suppose the cursor is in the middle of the word, if I play around and press enter and backspace, two numbers will show up on a line. Is there a CSS-only way of fixing this so only one number per line, and the line numbers still match up?

```css
pre {
    background: #303030;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
}

pre span {
  display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    counter-increment: line;
}
pre span:before {
      
      content: counter(line);
      display: inline-block;

      padding: 0 .5em;
      margin-right: .5em;
      color: #888;

}
```

```html
<pre contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64850246/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Just tested on Firefox, different layout so the snippet below does not number the lines. (FF just puts in `<br>` rather than any further HTML structure).

Will leave this answer up for a bit in case it helps someone get to a general answer for all common browsers.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
At least on Edge/Chrome the extra lines seem to be encased in div elements.

This snippet numbers the first line, which is just a span, in the same way that you have done but then numbers using the counter called line on the div immediate children of the pre rather than on the encased spans.

```css
pre {
  background: #303030;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  counter-reset: line 1;
}

pre>span::before {
  content: '1';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #888;
}

pre div {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  counter-increment: line;
}

pre div::before {
  content: counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<pre contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: It solves the original problem. But if you add another span, it still stays at one. But it helped me with the next step. But it still doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: You can set things for further spans at the same level as a div too, but nothing is going to get it working on FF other than some JavaScript coding.